# adding geolocation in webform using drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-webform

Im really newbie in drupal so maybe Im asking irrelevant question,
my goal is that the user will fill via google map api a location.
I watched in a youtube video (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hdzembWMgPc) that is possible with geolocation module but I dont know how to add it as a field in webform.

the final goal is to store in a table in a db the whole form results of the users.

hope you guys understood me.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Location module](https://drupal.org/project/location) along with [GMap module](http://drupal.org/project/gmap). Location [adds many fields to your content type form](https://drupal.org/documentation/modules/location). Use `Coordinate chooser` to add your location coordinates.

> Coordinate chooser - This consists of Latitude and Longitude fields. If you are also using the gmap module users can enter these coordinates by clicking on a map.

Here's [screencast](http://www.drupaltherapy.com/gmap) will walk you through using both modules.

Comment: the video doesnt work. in addition to that, I dont know how to add a field on my webform page that will be in type of location.

Comment: The location module adds the field automatically for you. I have provided a link for the module documentation. Also, check the [Configuration document](https://drupal.org/node/1038034).

Comment: I installed the gmap + location + cck location, but still the webform doesnt desplay me the location field. just the default fields (text field, date, time and etc..).